# How to use different static (global) variables in different objects?

Tags: c++, static

for now i have a class which represents a tree. Every node within this tree has exactly the same number of children, lets call it N. I managed this with a static variable for the class, which has the value of N, so this is basically a global variable.

My problem now is that i want to construct a different tree with the same class, but now the value of N should be different. So let's say i want to create the first tree with N=4 and the second with N=2. To save memory i only want to store those values of N once for the tree and not in every node of the tree. Is there a simple conceptual way to achieve this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you considered non-type template parameter?

Answer (score 2):

```
template<size_t N>
struct TreeNode {
    ...
    TreeNode<N>* children[N];
    ...
};
```

Used as TreeNode<2> or Treenode<7>

Comment: Yep, textbook usage.